# Change cell layout when traitCollection changes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, size-classes, adaptive-layout

I'm having problems adjusting a cell's layout when the horizontal size class changes.

My cell has a stackView and I want the axis to be Horizontal for Compact size class and Vertical for Regular.

This is what I tried:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    if previousTraitCollection?.horizontalSizeClass != traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass {
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    switch traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass {
    case .Compact:
        cell.stackView.axis = .Horizontal
    default:
        cell.stackView.axis = .Vertical
    }

    return cell
}
```

But the result is that not all cells update their layout, se the gif below.

**EDIT:**
I have confirmed that the axis is changed correctly by printing in `cellForItem` and in the cell class itself. So the issue seems to be that the cells are not redrawn..

[image: Cell layout problems]

Any suggestions how i should solve this?

[Github Repo](https://github.com/LarsJK/CellLayoutProblems)

Comment: Implement your reload in `traitCollectionDidChange`. By doing it `willChange` your cells still see the old trait collection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716136/where-to-update-autolayout-constraints-when-size-changes

Comment: Thanks but it still did not work. When i log out the `traitCollection` in `cellForItem` it is updated when using willChange as well but i will update my question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a call to `layoutIfNeeded()` to the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method in order to get the stack view to relayout its contents:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    switch traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass {
    case .Compact:
        cell.stackView.axis = .Horizontal
    default:
        cell.stackView.axis = .Vertical
    }

    cell.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing like that you could do it in the `prepareForReuse()` in the cell subclass